# DialogFragment with no title - ScrollView does not scroll

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` inside of `DialogFragment` that scrolled fine until I realized that the dialog shouldn't have a title, so I called (in `onCreateView`)

```
requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Then the `ScrollView` doesn't allow scrolling anymore and the bottom views are squished together. The `ScrollView` contains a vertical `LinearLayout` with some views that should overflow the screen.

Answer (score 4):

You should set **custom theme** for your **fragment dialog** by inheriting current android dialog and adding **windowSoftInputMode** option:

```
<style name="DialogFragmentStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateHidden|adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

Use your theme in your fragment dialog while creating constructor

> Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), **R.style.DialogFragmentStyle**);

```
public class MyFragmentDialog extends DialogFragment{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogFragmentStyle);

        //stuff

        return dialog;
    }  

    //... other methods

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
 onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
}
```